# How to use Virtual Machine to use programs in my pre-installed win 7 in my Ubuntu OS?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wine, wubi, vmware

My laptop was pre-installed with win 7. I used it for several years with personal data. I have installed Ubuntu recently alongside Win 7 for dual boot. Most of time, i just want to use Ubuntu for work. But i may need to run some programs that are only available in win 7. Now the problem is that after searching some info online, i found that VMware Player installation has to install a brand new win 7 inside my Ubuntu http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18768/run-windows-in-ubuntu-with-vmware-player/ .

What I really want is to use VMware Player to use the already existing win 7 with all my person data(previously installed programs) in my Ubuntu. From the following posts, it seems that this is very tricky (hardware environment problem? etc). see http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/ubuntu-windows-7-pc/

Do you think that in my case, it is better to use wine for running existing programs in my pre-installed win 7 inside my Ubuntu.

Or Someone suggests wubi in the post? I think that wubi is just installing Ubuntu inside Windows. Would this help running win 7 programs inside my Ubuntu?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is best to install windows in a virtual machine. It is possible to boot your windows install in a VM, but it is complicted and can break your windows install.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that it is a bad idea to use pre-installed windows in Virtual machine?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21961/can-i-virtualize-a-pre-installed-windows-7

Comment: Thanks. It seems that i should give up as a newbie for the sake of the integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally, I think you would be better off running it in a virtual machine, rather than the wine, because wine is very unstable when it comes to program installation.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that VM can not visualize already existing win 7 without taking up extra parition or disk space and causing other problems in many posts. Do you have any good suggestions?