# How to install dual boot Ubuntu (primary) while preserving Windows 10 with the installed applications as the second option?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, dell

I have Dell Latitude E7470 with Windows 10 and with the installed applications. Because of application licenses, I would like to be able to occasionally launch the Windows 10 as they are installed now.

The Ubuntu will probably be of the latest stable installation -- from scratch.

From what I have read, Dell laptops are certified to run Ubuntu. However, **is it possible** to create dual-boot installation **while preserving the previous Windows 10 with applications**?

In other words, I need to capture the "Windows 10 + applications" image somehow, and--while primarily using Ubuntu--be able to launch the older Win10+app when needed.

(I have searched for the information on my own; however, I have found only articles about installing dual-boot with Windows from scratch. Possibly, there is another alternative do get the same result.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I virtualize a pre-installed Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21961/can-i-virtualize-a-pre-installed-windows-7) and [Install Windows 7 through VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/187424/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can install Ubuntu in dual-boot.
As to how when you are asked how to install Ubuntu in the installation menu select custom and add a specific partition for your Ubuntu system.To make Ubuntu your primary  boot OS you  need to tweak it in your bios look for the boot drive settings and select the partition you have  installed Ubuntu.
Hope it has helped you!